# In my Android App, what is the contents of iabString to comply with GDPR in Flurry Ads?

Tags: android, flurry

I am trying to implement the GDPR compliance for Flurry Ads in my Android App. According to the Flurry page itself about GDPR:

init flurry with consent:

```
Map<String, String> consentStrings = new HashMap<>();

consentStrings.put(“IAB”, iabString);

new FlurryAgent.Builder()
```

And the contents of the iabString variable is..?

I searched a lot, and the only thing that I was able to find is a JSON generic list, but nothing specific to Flurry. Check the general expression:

https://vendorlist.consensu.org/vendorlist.json

So, do you have any idea of what is the EXACT string that I have to put in iabString? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This should be in IAB EU Transparency Consent Framework format:

https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/GDPR-Transparency-and-Consent-Framework/

Comment: At least, thanks for the intention to answer a very specific question. But frankly, you always simply point to general info, not really resolving what the developers are asking, and that is not really a "support". If you want to learn how to do it, you should study what Appodeal does, which is far from perfect, but they do strive to help. If you are not really helpful to the developers, they wont install Flurry, and your company will lose. So, this crucial aspect is ridiculously overlooked.